# how to perl for bi-directional communication with dsmadmc.exe?

Tags: perl, communication

I have simple web-form with a little js script that sends form values to a text box. This combined value becomes a database query.
This will be sendt to dsmadmc (TSM administrative command line).
How can I use perl to keep the dsmadmc process open for consecutive input/output without the dsmadmc process closing between each input command sent?

And how can I capture the output - this is to be sent back to the same web page, in a separate div.
Any thought, anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably [IPC::Open2](http://search.cpan.org/~dapm/perl-5.10.1/lib/IPC/Open2.pm) could help. It allows to read/write to/from both input and output of an external process.

Beware of deadlocks though (i.e. situations where both your code and the app wait for their counterpart). You might want to use [IO::Select](http://search.cpan.org/~gbarr/IO-1.25/lib/IO/Select.pm) to handle that.

P.S. I don't know how these modules behave on windows (.exe?..), but from a quick google search it looks like they are compatible.

Comment: Thanks, I was heading in that direction and appreciate confirmation. Looks like the IPC::Open2 will handle it. Where would you think the deadlock might occur?

Comment: See topic "avoiding deadlocks" in `perldoc perlipc`, they'll explain it *better*.